# jQuery menu item selected

Tags: jquery

I all!

I have this menu:

```
  <ul id="navigation">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?page=Entidad">Entidad</a></li>
  </ul>
```

With jQuery I'm tring to apply the class .active when a menu item is clicked, as:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("li a").click(function(){
           $(this).parent().find("li").addClass('active');   
      });
  });
```

It doesn't work, could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parent` of `a` is `li` it self so you do not need to `find` li.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjk5g/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("li a").click(function(){
           $(this).parent().addClass('active');   
      });
});
```

**Edit** To remove the class from previous elements and add to current

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjk5g/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("li a").click(function(event){
           $('#navigation li').removeClass();
           $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      });
});
```

Comment: Hi Adil, your code works fine, but by clicking on the link, I reload the page, without applying the class to the "li" element. :(

Comment: I used  event.preventDefault(); to cancel the default behavior of link , either you do that or bind event to li if you do not need reload.

Comment: The problem is I need to create a link to some pages, and then apply the class at to the li element, but reloading the page I loss the jquery action. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When handling the click of `a`, `li` is the parent item, so just do:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

Are you sure of this, though, as I would have thought it sensible to make the link the active thing? Just an observation.

Answer (score 1):

Your page will get refreshed once the hyperlink is clicked so this code `$(this).parent().addClass('active')` will not going to work.

Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
                var page = getParameterByName('page');
                $("#navigation a:contains('" + page + "')").parent().addClass('active');
            });

            function getParameterByName(name)
            {
              name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
              var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
              var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
              var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
              if(results == null)
                return "Home";
              else
                return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active'); //  $(this).parent() selects list element
```

No need to find again li element there.